# Excel; assistance with formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I'm having an issue using the correct COUNTIF formula in excel.
Wondering if anyone can help.

[image]

Comment: Note: best bet is to include text/question/description in text of Q itself (as opposed to embedded within a screenshot) - that way other users are able to edit if necessary more freely.  Couple of spelling errors in the text but no major biggie; also - your screenshot does not include column/row headers (so not easy to know which cell is N18/N5 / N9 etc.!)  Hope soln below helps!

Answer (score 0):

Countifs will do the trick - screenshot refers:

```
=COUNTIFS(E5:E10,"="&"",F5:F10,"<>"&"")
```

[image: Countifs function for # changes]